# Color all adjacent same tiles iteratively

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I try to create a paint bucket tool. I need to find all adjacents points of the point I clicked, and change their color if they have the same color than the original. The color need to propagate on all points with same color. The propagation can only be done on 4 directions (no diagonals).

I can do this easily recursively, but sadly I get an error when the map is too big :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This is a basic example to reproduce the problem, and I would like to transform it to iterative way:

```
// Fill the map
var map = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 500; x++){
    var row = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < 500; y++){
        row.push(1);
    }
    map.push(row);
}

var paintTile = function(x, y){
    // If X or Y is out of map range
    if (x < 0 || x >= 500 || y < 0 || y >= 500){
        return
    }

    // If this tile is already painted in new color
    if (map[x][y] == 0){
        return;
    }

    // Draw tile with new color
    map[x][y] = 0;

    // Paint all adjacent tiles
    paintTile(x - 1, y);
    paintTile(x + 1, y);
    paintTile(x, y - 1);
    paintTile(x, y + 1);
};

paintTile(0, 0);
```

In this example, all the map is populated of "1" (let's say it's white color), and I transform them to "0" (black color), but I get this `stack size` error.

Regards

Comment: Recursive approach is easier, but all the function calls can fill your stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean Flood fill algorithm?

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill:

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. Set Q to the empty queue.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Add node to Q.
 4. For each element N of Q:
 5.     If the color of N is equal to target-color:
 6.         Set w and e equal to N.
 7.         Move w to the west until the color of the node to the west of w no longer matches target-color.
 8.         Move e to the east until the color of the node to the east of e no longer matches target-color.
 9.         For each node n between w and e:
10.             Set the color of n to replacement-color.
11.             If the color of the node to the north of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
12.             If the color of the node to the south of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
13. Continue looping until Q is exhausted.
14. Return.
```

Comment: @AlexD: Link only answers are generally frowned upon (the idea being that the answer should answer the question without a need to go elsewhere, links would be just for extra detail, etc.). Your answer would be greatly improved by putting the algorithm from that page into your answer.

Comment: BTW this is exactly the algorithm is used, and it works well, thx for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of tiles you need to process and tiles you have processed. Put your first tile in the ToBeProcessed list and then loop repeatedly until your to be processed list is empty.

On each loop firstly check if you want to recolour this tile or not. If you don't then remove it from the ToBeProcessed and go to the next cycle of the loop. If it does then do the normal processing (ie change the colour). Then  add the adjacent tiles to the ToBeProcessed list if they aren't on the already processed list (or already in the ToBeProcessed list).

Then at the end of your loop iteration remove the current item from the ToBeProcessed list.

Answer (score 0):

here is a video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvacRISl99Y

Instead of using complex logic to track previously verified neighbor spaces, I have a 2D array that records all the verified spaces. Reading from the verified array is 2-3 instructions: IF pixel[23,23] is verified, THEN fill it and check it's neighbors.