# How do I fill an area using a non-recursive algorithm?

Tags: javascript, canvas, optimization

I am trying to create a basic paint application using `canvas` (which refers to the 2DContext of the element in the code). However, with the current time, all browsers give up and say that `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. How can I improve on this code, to be able to fill larger regions?

I start the code as `fillAround(Math.round(x), Math.round(y), colorAt(Math.round(x), Math.round(y)), fillcolor);` where x and y are the coordinates of the click.

```
    function hexToRgb(hex) {
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? {
            r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
            g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
            b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        } : null;
    }

    function colorToRgb(arr) {
        return {
            r: arr[0],
            g: arr[1],
            b: arr[2]
        }
    }

    function colorAt(xp, yp) {
        return colorToRgb(canvas.getImageData(xp, yp, 1, 1).data);
    }

    function setColorAt(xp, yp, fill) {
        var color = canvas.getImageData(xp, yp, 1, 1)
        var set = hexToRgb(fill);
        color.data[0] = set.r;
        color.data[1] = set.g;
        color.data[2] = set.b;
        canvas.putImageData(color, xp, yp);
    }

    function sameColor(a, b) {
        return a.r == b.r && a.g == b.r && a.b == b.b;
    }

    function fillAround(xp, yp, original, fill) {
        if (sameColor(colorAt(xp, yp), original)) {
            setColorAt(xp, yp, fill);
            if (sameColor(colorAt(xp + 1, yp), original)) {
                fillAround(xp + 1, yp, original, fill);
            }
            if (sameColor(colorAt(xp - 1, yp), original)) {
                fillAround(xp - 1, yp, original, fill);
            }
            if (sameColor(colorAt(xp, yp + 1), original)) {
                fillAround(xp, yp + 1, original, fill);
            }
            if (sameColor(colorAt(xp, yp - 1), original)) {
                fillAround(xp, yp - 1, original, fill);
            }
        }
    }
```

The hex to rgb converter is from [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb#) .

The updated code (with the help of @trincot)

```
    var canvasData;

    function hexToRgb(hex) {
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? {
            r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
            g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
            b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        } : null;
    }

    function colorToRgb(arr) {
        return {
            r: arr[0],
            g: arr[1],
            b: arr[2]
        }
    }

    function colorAt(xp, yp) {
        return colorToRgb(canvasData.data.slice(4 * canvasTag.width * (yp - 1) + 4 * (xp + 1), 4 * canvasTag.widthwidth * (yp - 1) + 4 * xp + 8));
    }

    function setColorAt(xp, yp, fill) {
        var set = hexToRgb(fill);
        var o = 4 * canvasTag.width * (yp - 1) + 4 * (xp + 1);
        canvasData.data[o] = set.r;
        canvasData.data[o + 1] = set.g;
        canvasData.data[o + 2] = set.b;
    }

    function sameColor(a, b) {
        return a.r == b.r && a.g == b.r && a.b == b.b;
    }

    function fillAround(xp, yp, original, fill) {
        const stack = [[xp, yp]];
        while (stack.length) {
            const [xp, yp] = stack.pop();
            if (!sameColor(colorAt(xp, yp), original)) continue;
            setColorAt(xp, yp, fill);
            stack.push([xp + 1, yp], [xp - 1, yp], [xp, yp + 1], [xp, yp - 1]); 
        }
    }
```

and is called through

```
canvasData = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, canvasTag.width, canvasTag.height);
fillAround(Math.round(x), Math.round(y), colorAt(Math.round(x), Math.round(y)), fillcolor);
canvas.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Seems your asking about a very specific issue (stack overflow) but you've pasted a whole application. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I assume you're google searched for what that error message means. It would help the community if you edit your question to be specifically about converting your recursive algorithm to one that is not recursive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-recursive implementation of Flood Fill algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865922/non-recursive-implementation-of-flood-fill-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, stack memory is limited. Your code gets into very deeply nested calls of `fillAround`, which consume the available stack memory completely.

Without changing anything in the other logic, I would suggest replacing the recursive calls with a loop in which you manage your own stack:

```
function fillAround(xp, yp, original, fill) {
    const stack = [[xp, yp]]; // Initially the stack has one pair of coordinates
    while (stack.length) { // Keep iterating while there is work to do...
        const [xp, yp] = stack.pop(); // Get one pair of coordinates from the stack
        if (!sameColor(colorAt(xp, yp), original)) continue; // Skip it
        setColorAt(xp, yp, fill);
        // Push the neighbors onto the stack for later processing:
        stack.push([xp + 1, yp], [xp - 1, yp], [xp, yp + 1], [xp, yp - 1]); 
    }
}
```

This alone will not improve the speed, it will only avoid the stack memory exception.

To get better performance, you should not read/write each pixel individually with calls like:

```
canvas.getImageData(xp, yp, 1, 1)
canvas.putImageData(color, xp, yp)
```

... but use the power of the last two arguments of `getImageData`: read the whole canvas area into memory, at once, make the changes in memory, and then write that back with only *one* call of `setImageData`.

Comment: it seems rather slow when filling larger areas, is there a better way, like some other drawing programs do?

Comment: Did you see my comment and addition? ;-)

Comment: after commenting, and a reload, yes :)

Comment: the load into memory doesn't seem to improve a lot unfortunately

Comment: There are several other optimisations possible. For instance you call `hexToRgb(fill)` many times, but with the same value. For gaining speed you should give up on the otherwise nice conversion functions and do only the bare minimum manipulation necessary. Don't convert the image array to plain object, ...etc.

Comment: brillant sollution. I would add also a check to validate the direction and discard some stack inserts.