# What is the logical difference between these codes?

Tags: c++

This is my solution, which receives a heap buffer overflow (out of bounds):

```
void FFHelper(vector<vector<int>>& image, int i, int j, int newColor, int oldColor)
{
    static int m = image.size(); 
    static int n = image[0].size();

    if (i < 0 || j < 0 
        || i >= m || j >= n 
        || image[i][j] != oldColor) 
    {
       return;
    }

    image[i][j] = newColor;

    FFHelper(image, i+1, j, newColor, oldColor);
    FFHelper(image, i-1, j, newColor, oldColor);
    FFHelper(image, i, j+1, newColor, oldColor);
    FFHelper(image, i, j-1, newColor, oldColor);
}

vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int color)
{
    FFHelper(image, sr, sc, color, image[sr][sc]);

    return image;
}
```

where it is guaranteed that `0 <= sr < m` and `0 <= sc < n` where `image` is `m x n`.

This is a code that receives no buffer overflow:

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& image, int i, int j, int val, int newColor)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= image.size() 
       || j < 0 || j>= image[0].size() 
       || image[i][j] == newColor || image[i][j] != val)
    {
        return;
    }

    image[i][j] = newColor;

    dfs(image, i - 1, j, val, newColor);
    dfs(image, i + 1, j, val, newColor);
    dfs(image, i, j - 1, val, newColor);
    dfs(image, i, j + 1, val, newColor);
}
    
vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, 
int newColor)
{
    int val = image[sr][sc];

    dfs(image, sr, sc, val, newColor);

    return image;
}
```

What is the difference? I seriously don't see it. Someone from `codereview.stackexchange` suggested I post here.

Comment: In the fist version you use `static` variables to hold the width and height. This will break if you call `floodFill` the 2nd time, with an image smaller than the first (because the `static`s will not be updated).

Comment: `j+1` can go out of bounds in both.  and don't use static Also don't use `using namespace std;`. And know that when using 2D vectors for images each line can end up in a total different part of memory (which can be a perfomance issue).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think that this issue by itself (the `j+1` issue) will not cause a problem, because the function will exit on the first `if` and will not do the out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @wohlstad I see that now too, it will just do an unecessary extra recurse call which will then fail. It is just that from code review experience I trigger on loops with `<= `or `>=` in them. It is uncommon and thus surprising.

Comment: OP, you may in the future use a debugger to identify issues like this :)

Comment: I see @wohlstad . Before i was passing in the variables `m` and `n` recursively as arguments, but this led to stack overflow, probably because they end up in caller-saved registers.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that call to `.size()` on every recursive iteration? That was what I was hoping with the `static` variables.

Comment: @user20896951why do you want to avoid that ? `std::vector::size` is O(1) and typically very fast. It does not require to traverse the vector.

Comment: @user20896951 As you get more experienced, you'll realise that your solution (using static variables) is worse than the 'problem' it is solving.

Comment: A stack overflow in recursive functions is usually the result of invalid end conditions. A bug in your if statement for example and has no relation to whether your local variables are static or not.  Also try to give your variables better names (width/height, x, y etc.). Also you can query the image size once in your first function and pass that on

Comment: If you care about performance, see @PepijnKramer's comment above about keeping the whole image in continuous memory.

Comment: Just don't use recursion, it doesn't scale well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865922/non-recursive-implementation-of-flood-fill-algorithm